# HiveServer2 hangs when I start it

Tags: hive

I am trying to setup HDP 3.1.0 on Oracle Linux 7.

Ambari, HDFS and HIVE Metastore services are already running but HiveServer2 is not starting.

When I try to start it manually:

```
# hive --service hiveserver2
```

I get this after several minutes of waiting:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/phoenix/phoenix-5.0.0.3.1.0.0-78-server.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2018-12-15 14:15:28: Starting HiveServer2
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive Session ID = 99822aa9-957a-439e-904e-d9adce9a7893
Hive Session ID = fa34c442-4598-4f85-9493-daaf93804164
Hive Session ID = ed8de700-4ebf-4985-ae13-830b306be0e7
Hive Session ID = 6093d16b-53f0-4e21-9429-8046d3f3917a
Hive Session ID = a4fc572d-d56f-4c8a-97a0-8fc8bc115233
Hive Session ID = 02fdb753-45f7-4009-8283-bf3d5eef00b2
Hive Session ID = 47be06ad-42d2-4281-83f3-7e9b4cac1690
Hive Session ID = dae77692-3296-464f-995b-cb45a98d2e09
Hive Session ID = c4d49aa0-f829-4765-adbc-9afd5414775b
Hive Session ID = 8e26f8d8-bb01-4384-bfa2-8cb5ea66d1e8
```

This is what netstat is reporting:

```
# netstat -ntpl | egrep "10000|10001|10002"
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:10001     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      422/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:10002     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26918/java
```

Nobody is listening on port 10000 :(

This is what I have in /hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
  <value>10001</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.webui.port</name>
  <value>10002</value>
</property>
```

I assume I can ignore SLF4J warnings, correct? What else should I check?

Comment: @Gaurang After re-installing everything but with no changes to configuration I now have:    `#  netstat -ltpn | egrep "10000|10001|10002"
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26066/java
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26066/java`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that that this service was trying to grab more memory than 1024 MB allowed by the default **/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml** setting:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>1024</value>
</property>
```

I increased that limit to 1792 and the issue was resolved.